# Find an empty space in a binary image that can fit a shape

Tags: python

I have this image

[image]

I need to find an empty area that can fit this shape

[image]

so that the end result is something like this

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I couldn't think of a way actually

Comment: Can there be any other shape than rectangles?

Comment: @UnquoteQuote yes, any shape

Comment: @UnquoteQuote but if there is an efficient way that works with rectangles it would be sufficient

Comment: In any case it does look like a problem solvable with matrix convolution:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#/media/File:Convolution_of_box_signal_with_itself2.gif

As you can treat both image as simple matrix this could give you an idea. I've never done something like this though so it's only an idea.

Comment: Otherwise, programmatically, I don't see any other solution than taking the shape's border and try to insert a line, one at a time, starting with each of the big image's points one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple yet naive solution to this problem. It uses 2D convolution as mentioned by [UnquoteQuote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19417012/unquotequote).

```py
import random
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# load images
image = (cv2.imread('image.jpg').mean(axis=2) > 127).astype(np.float32)
shape = (cv2.imread('shape.jpg').mean(axis=2) > 127).astype(np.float32)

# perform 2D convolution
conv = sig.convolve2d(image, shape, mode='valid')
solutions = np.where(conv == 0)

# draw some solutions
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 4))
for i in range(4):
    r = random.randint(0, solutions[0].shape[0] - 1)
    x, y = solutions[0][r], solutions[1][r]

    solution_plot = np.zeros((*image.shape, 3))
    solution_plot[:, :, 0] = image
    solution_plot[x:x + shape.shape[0], y:y + shape.shape[1], 1] = shape

    plt.subplot(1, 4, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(solution_plot)

plt.show()
```

Example results:
[image]

This algorithm finds all possible solutions. If you only need one, you can optimize it so that it gets a random `(x, y)` point and perform dot product of the shape and a cropped image area `[x:x+shape_width, y:y+shape_height]` to check if there is a space until you find the right point.

This can be done for example like this:

```py
while True:
    x = random.randint(0, image.shape[0] - shape.shape[0])
    y = random.randint(0, image.shape[1] - shape.shape[1])

    if np.sum(shape*image[x:x + shape.shape[0], y:y + shape.shape[1]]) == 0:
        break

# x, y is the solution
```

Compared to convolution this one is much faster (but it depends on the number of the solutions):

- convolution: `6.65 s ± 21.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
- random search: `1.31 ms ± 31.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great, and thanks to @UnquoteQuote as well